# How to sort array of object with key property?

Tags: javascript

I want to sort and array of objects with the property key name.
My Array of objects looks like this:

```
var array = [
  {
     'version2': {
        name: 'abc'
     }
  }, 
  {
     'version1': {
        name: 'xyz'
     }
  }
]
```

The output expected is something like this:

```
var array = [
  {
     'version1': {
        name: 'xyz'
     }
  }, 
  {
     'version2': {
        name: 'abc'
     }
  }
]
```

I tried sorting with this solution but no luck

```
var abc = array.sort(function(a, b){return Object.keys(a)[0] - Object.keys(b)[0]});
console.log(abc);
```

The output was same. Please help me out with the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Taki No, the answer on the mentioned portal sort by key value and I needed the sorting key name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use localeCompare. Assuming each of the objects have only one key

```js
var array = [{
    'version2': {
      name: 'abc'
    }
  },
  {
    'version1': {
      name: 'xyz'
    }
  }
]
const sorted = array.sort((a, b) => {
  return Object.keys(a)[0].localeCompare(Object.keys(b)[0])
});
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line (compare expression):

```
var abc = array.sort(function(a, b){return (Object.keys(a)[0] > Object.keys(b)[0])? 1: -1});
```

Or just:

```
var abc = array.sort((a, b) => (Object.keys(a)[0] > Object.keys(b)[0])? 1: -1);
```

Comment: @Tales Fixed the issue. `a > b` works on Firefox only. but `a > b ? 1: -1` works on Chrome too.